# How to share cookie for the web applications hosted on same IIS

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have two applications hosted on same IIS server. These applications have same users. Once authenticated, I am creating cookie using Angular like below:

```
$cookies.putObject(key, cookie)
```

I have kept the **key** same for both the applications.

Now, when I login to one application, this cookie gets created. But when I try to access second application, below code reads null.

```
$cookies.getObject(key)
```

Can I read this cookie from other application so that after login to one application, user need not to enter login credentials to other application.

Thanks.

Comment: No. You Cant. That would mean I could create a site called ripuoff.com and have you come to my site while logged into yourbank.com and then ask your browser for the cookie for yourbank.com. Google same-origin-policy. If you want to do SSO then you need to base your credentials around a trusted 3rd party.

Answer (score -1):

you might be able use localstore to share data but its a huge security risk. I would not do it. I recommend using sessionstore instead och cookies when it comes to authentification. In your case it's be better to use some single signed on solution. Its a lot of them out there.  OR: if you host both applications. Maybe you should merge the applications into one?

Comment: The storage API is subject to same-origin-policy as well.